# how could i solve ValueError?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Good day all. 
I am working on code from Github. It consists of 4 files as follows

- **data.py** contains code to construct a TensorFlow data pipeline where input perturbations are handled by the CPU.
- **graphs.py** contains code to construct various computational graphs, whose output connects to an IIC head.
- **models_iic.py** contains the Cluster IIC class, which implements unsupervised clustering. [image: models_iic.py screenshot]
- **utils.py** contains some utility functions.
  When running models_iic.py appears this error
  [image: utils.py screenshot]

Comment: Do add the codes & errors  within the question rather than attaching images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I used the requirements file and it worked
But look at the output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmTsx.jpg)